# timezone differences between utime() and stat()

Tags: winapi, timezone, stat

I have a Windows C program that downloads files from a unix server along with their modification times.  It then saves a local copy in a cache and sets its timestamp to match the timestamp on the server - so it won't need to pull a fresh copy if the local copy is up to date.

Anyway, it uses utime() to set the timestamp to the binary value that was reported by the unix host, and then uses stat() to read back the timestamp to check whether the file is out of date.  This used to work, but I just noticed that it doesn't work any more.

For what it's worth, the discrepency in the times is 3600 seconds (1 hour), so I'm guessing this has something to do with how utime and/or stat handle the timezone.  I just figured that stat would report back to me the same modification time value I set in utime, but apparently that's (no longer?) true. I've seen another post on here that mentions Windows implementation of stat messes up daylight savings time - so that may be it.

Is there a more correct way to do this in Windows - while still using the POSIX time functions.  Remember, I'm trying to get the binary mod time of the local file (as reported by Windows) to match the mod time of the host file (as reported by stat on unix).

Here's some sample code that shows the issue.  fc->timestamp is the value sent from the server.  I copy it to utimes, call utime() and stat(), and statbuf.st_mtime differs from the others by 3600 seconds:

```
// Set the local file's timestamp to the host's value
utimes.actime = utimes.modtime = fc->timestamp;
utime(szTempPath2, &utimes);
// Now call stat to see what time registers there.
if (stat(szTempPath2, &statbuf) == 0) {
if (fc->timestamp != statbuf.st_mtime)
        fc->timestamp = statbuf.st_mtime;
}

When I'm done the values are:
fc->timestamp = 1359772839
utimes.modtime = 1359772839
statbuf.st_mtime = 1359776439 <<== this is 3600 more than the others
```

Comment: Okay.  I found another post that explains (in a way I don't quite get) that on an NTFS filesystem, stat() returns the wrong time when daylight savings time is not in effect.  Off by an hour as I noted above.  And if I turn off the 'Automatically adjust clock for daylight savings time' checkbox, the problem goes away.  But my question remains.  Is there a safe way to get the local Windows file's timestamp to match the unix host's timestamp?  The host isn't using 64-bit UTC and has the 1970 base year, so switching to those functions on the Windows side won't work - will it?

Comment: These POSIX functions are not "Windows" in general. They're provided by whichever C runtime library you're using. I wasn't able to reproduce this using the first C runtime to be officially distributed as a public Windows component (i.e. the Universal CRT). I suggest you inspect what's actually set by `_utime`. Call `GetFileTime` to check the  `lpLastWriteTime` (100 ns units since 1601-01-01, UTC). Divide by 10,000,000 and subtract 11,644,473,600 to convert this to a Unix timestamp.

Comment: I tried your GetFileTime approach, and after converting lpLastWriteTime to a unix timestamp, it matches the 'off by 1 hour' value that statbuf.st_mtime produces.  So, I guess that means that what I really need to use is SetFileTime instead of utime() - and then stat will just work.

Comment: Yep.  I just tried that.  if I reverse your time calculation (convert the unix timestamp to Windows UTC) and use SetFileTime to set the lpLastWriteTime, a subsequent call to stat returns the original unix file time and my cache timestamp check succeeds.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out utime() is the culprit.

If you use utime to set the mod time, both stat() and GetFileTime() will return your time + 1 hour if the NTFS daylight savings time problem is in effect.  But if you use SetFileTime, both stat() and GetFileTime will return the time you set - regardless of the way NTFS handles daylight savings time.

So, it's like erkysun described in the comments above, except that you need to reverse the windows-to-unix timestamp calculation and instead convert the unix timestamp to windows UTC microseconds since 1/1/1601 (using the constants erkysun provided).  Like so:

```
ulong     unix_timestamp;
ULONGLONG win_timestamp;
ULARGE_INTEGER li;
HFILE     hFile;
FILETIME  filetime;

   if (hFile = CreateFile(szTempPath2, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 
                          FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL)) {
      // Convert the unix timestamp to Windows UTC time
      // 1/1/1970 unix base date (seconds) to 1/1/1601 windows base date
      win_timestamp = unix_timestamp + 11644473600;
      // seconds to 100's of nanoseconds
      win_timestamp *= 10000000;
      // Copy the long long int into filetime high/low and
      // use to set the access and mod times.
      li.QuadPart = win_timestamp;
      filetime.dwHighDateTime = li.HighPart;
      filetime.dwLowDateTime = li.LowPart;
      SetFileTime(hFile, NULL, &filetime, &filetime);
      CloseHandle(hFile);
  }
```